# system.string can't bind blob

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

In my .NET program,When I store a data which length > 2000 in oracle,I get the error

```
system.string can't bind  blob
```

The filed type is `blob` and the program's data type is 'string'.

So,I want to know how to store a data which length > 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blob field is represented in .net as a byte array, you can convert your string from/to a byte array like this:

```
byte[] blob = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(yourstring);
string yourstring = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(blob);
```